# Ambigouos columns 'data' in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load a dataframe with an CSV but I'm getting this error:

```
Reference 'data' is ambiguous
```

I'm defining the schema when reading, but probably because the data in the CSV have descriptions with commas in it, the schema shows 2 new columns called just "data":

```
root
 |-- CD_SK_PRODUTO_ATG: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CD_VENDA_PRODUTO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CD_VENDA_REFIL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NO_PRODUTO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ID_REFIL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DC_RECOMENDACAO_PUBLICO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DC_USO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NO_LINHA_PRODUTO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CD_CONTEXTO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DT_ULTIMA_ATUALIZACAO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CD_USUARIO_ATUALIZACAO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SG_PAIS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: date (nullable = true)
 |-- data: date (nullable = true)
```

Since the 2 new columns have the same name I can't do anything with the Dataframe. I've tried to remove the columns with `df.drop()`, selecting just a couple of columns with `df.select()`, limiting the result with `df.limit(1)`, infer the schema when reading...

But the error `Reference 'data' is ambiguous` still shows up.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: have you checked in the `csv` file where these fields are coming from?

Comment: The CSV have 12 columns. But when I try to open it in excel, I'm guessing because come comments have commas in them, a few columns get dislocated. Unfortunately, I don't have access when the CSV is generated so I could fix the columns with double quotes. I was hopping for some sort of function like "dropErrors"

Comment: cant you open it in a text editor?

Comment: There is `DROPMALFORMED` which ignores the whole corrupted records while reading csv files.

Comment: i think you can read your csv as RDD[String] with sc.textfile and then drop errors from your csv finally transform the rdd to a dataframe

Comment: I've tried the DROPMALFORMED, didn't work =/ I'll try the RDD and post the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response, guys!

The suggestion from Mehrez worked with a little transformation. The final version look like this:

```
product_rdd = sc.textFile(product_path).map(lambda x: x.split('","'))
results["PRODUCT_DATA"] = product_rdd.toDF(product_schema)
```

I had to split using `","`, not the best solution, but worked for what I was needed :)

Thanks once again!